# Nested Loops with non-nested arrays in handlebars.net

Tags: c#, handlebars.js, handlebars.net

I'm trying to build a handlebars template for a heatmap by day over a range of 15 days before current to 60 days into the future.

Here is the model I am using for my template

```
public class HeatMapDto
{
    public IEnumerable<HeatMapDateDto> HeatMapDates { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ProductDto> Products { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the relevant piece of my template

```
<table style='width: 2000px'>
    <tr>
        <th style='width: 100px'>Product</th>
        <th style='width: 100px'>EAStart</th>
        <th style='width: 100px'>Release</th>
        {{#each HeatMapDates}}
        <th style='width: 50px'>{{FormattedDate}}</th>
        {{/each}}
    </tr>
    {{#each Products}}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ProductName}}</td>
        <td>{{FormattedEarlyAccessStart}}</td>
        <td>{{FormattedReleaseDate}}</td>
        {{#each @root.HeatMapDates}}
        <td style="background-color:{{SelectCellColor DateValue EarlyAccessDate ReleaseDate '#747dff' '3d07ff' '#8cb871' '#e9fbff'}}{{/SelectCellColor}}">&nbsp;</td>
        {{/each}}
    </tr>
    {{/each}}
</table>
```

`HeatMapDates`is populated with all the days for the report and I can iterate over them to generate the column headers.

```
public class HeatMapDateDto
{
    public DateTime DateValue { get; set; }

    public string FormattedDate => DateValue.ToString("MM/dd");
}

public class HeatMapProductDto
{
    public string ProductName { get; set; }

    public DateTime? EarlyAccessStart { get; set; }

    public DateTime? ReleaseDate { get; set; }

    public string FormattedEarlyAccessStart => EarlyAccessStart?.ToString("MM/dd");

    public string FormattedReleaseDate => ReleaseDate?.ToString("MM/dd");
}
```

`SelectCellColor` is a handler I have registered in my code, and when this is called into, the three dates are undefined and the context is a `HeatMapDate`.  It's purpose is to determine which of the 4 colors passed in to apply to the cell: InEarlyAcccess, ReleaseDate, PostRelease, or default color, in that order.

if I do the outer loop like this `{{#each product in Products}}`, Handlebars.Net throws an exception:

> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains more than one element

Any idea on how to make this work to iterate over the two arrays when they aren't parent-child?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handlebars doesn't support the `variableName in` syntax, only the `#each enumerable` syntax.

You can still use nested loops - each block creates a new context, and the parent context is always accessible via `../`. So in your case, in the outer loop `this` (or just the implicit context) would be the current item, and in the nested loop, `../` would refer to the current item in the outer loop.